# mysql GROUP_CONCAT always return blob I even change all the group_concat_max_len=100000000 help?

Tags: mysql, blob, group-concat

I have try almost every tutorial on the internet trying to change group_concat_max_len but as file my.ini didnt exist  group_concat_max_len in wamp server, and I execute the following querys show variables like 'group%'; and SET @@group_concat_max_len = 9999999; but It say any rows affected how can I fix that? I dont find a solution please help

I already do a query but I does not work It returns blob

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=4096;
SELECT correo_id_correo, GROUP_CONCAT(destinatario_id_usuario SEPARATOR ',') FROM correo_has_usuario GROUP BY correo_id_correo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [manual page for GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> The result type is TEXT or BLOB unless group_concat_max_len is less
>   than or equal to 512, in which case the result type is VARCHAR or
>   VARBINARY.

So increasing `group_concat_max_len` will not return `VARCHAR` or `VARBINARY`. You'd need to *decrease* it.

Comment: I tried this SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=2000;
SELECT correo_id_correo, GROUP_CONCAT(destinatario_id_usuario SEPARATOR ',') FROM correo_has_usuario GROUP BY correo_id_correo; bit It does not work I also decrease but any other solution?

Comment: Please read carefully: it needs to be less or equal than **512**. Anyway, what exactly are you trying accomplish?

Comment: hablas espaniol? do you speak spanish? I already solved with your help thanks you, but I tried to change it the my.ini file and  group_concat_max_len property does not exist do you know why?

Comment: It's not mandatory to specify all settings. MySQL will use default values for almost everything. Add the line yourself. (Yes, I can speak Spanish, but I remind you this is an English speaking site.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT concat(CONVERT(column1,char(8))," , ") AS id,
       group_concat(CONVERT(column2, CHAR(20)) separator '|') AS result 
FROM `tablename` 
WHERE 1 group by column1
```

Here `CONVERT` will convert value of field column1 into a char type. and `CONVERT` function will be work on it.

Source: [Coderhub](https://coderhub.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/apply-group_concat-and-concat-on-a-integer-type-value/)